# How to apply multiple filters on some div's without forgetting the first filter?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some `div` elements and have implemented a filter on them.

My problem is that if I use multiple different filters then it only applies one filter at once. How could I make it apply multiple filters like "genre" and "artist" *at the same time*?

I tried making 2 times the same filter but with another name but now it only applies the latest filter.

```js
//filter
filterSelection('all');

function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName('filterDiv');
  if (c == 'all') c = '';
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    RemoveClass(x[i], 'show');
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) AddClass(x[i], 'show');
  }
}

filterSelectionComposer('all');

function filterSelectionComposer(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName('filterDiv');
  if (c == 'all') c = '';
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    RemoveClass(x[i], 'show');
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) AddClass(x[i], 'show');
  }
}

function AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(' ');
  arr2 = name.split(' ');
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += ' ' + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

function RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(' ');
  arr2 = name.split(' ');
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(' ');
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById('myBtnContainer');
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName('btn');
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(' active', '');
    this.className += ' active';
  });
}

//searchbar
let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.filterDiv');

function liveSearch() {
  console.log('livesearch');
  let search_query = document.getElementById('myInput').value;

  //Use innerText if all contents are visible
  //Use textContent for including hidden elements
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    if (
      cards[i].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(search_query.toLowerCase())
    ) {
      cards[i].classList.remove('is-hidden');
    } else {
      cards[i].classList.add('is-hidden');
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('myInput').oninput = liveSearch;
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>IMSLP</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a href="pages/subscription.php">Subscription</a>
    <a href="pages/login.php">Login</a>
    <a href="pages/about.php">About</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name" />
  <div id="filters">
    <div id="myBtnContainer">
      <p>Period</p>
      <button onclick="filterSelection('Barok')" class="btn">Barok</button>
      <button onclick="filterSelection('Classic')" class="btn">
            Classic
          </button>
      <button onclick="filterSelection('Renaissance')" class="btn">
            Renaissance
          </button>
      <button onclick="filterSelection('Romantic')" class="btn">
            Romantic
          </button>
    </div>
    <div id="myBtnContainer">
      <p>Composer</p>
      <button onclick="filterSelectionComposer('DiLasso')" class="btn">De Lassus</button>
      <button onclick="filterSelectionComposer('Bach')" class="btn">
            Bach
          </button>
      <button onclick="filterSelectionComposer('Vivaldi')" class="btn">
            Vivaldi
          </button>
      <button onclick="filterSelectionComposer('Schubert')" class="btn">
            Schubert
          </button>
      <button onclick="filterSelectionComposer('Tchaikovsky')" class="btn">
            Tchaikovsky
          </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="myUL">
    <div class="filterDiv Renaissance DiLasso">Lagrime de San Pietro</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Renaissance">Sweelinck</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Classic">Haydn</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Romantic">Wagner</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Classic">Mozart</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Barok Bach">Bach</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Classic">Beethoven</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Barok">Händel</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Barok Vivaldi">Vivaldi</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Renaissance">Obrecht</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Romantic Schubert">Schubert</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Romantic Tchaikovsky">Tchaikovsky</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is much more complex than it needs to be. Using the more modern `classList` API you can easily update the classes of an element without needing to pull apart the `className` string.

To do what you require you can toggle a `class` on the buttons when they're clicked to indicate they are active for filtering. The buttons can be edited to hold `data` attributes which are the classes to filter by that button.
You can then use this to build an array of classnames to display which can be converted to a selector string to match against all the composers.

Also note that `onclick` attributes are no longer good practice and should be avoided. Modern convention is to assign event handlers unobtrusively using `addEventListener()`.

Here's a full working example:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const composers = document.querySelectorAll('.filterDiv');

buttons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
  filterSelection();
}))

function filterSelection() {
  const filters = [...document.querySelectorAll('.btn.active')].map(el => el.dataset.filter);
  composers.forEach(c => c.style.display = filters.length === 0 || c.matches(`.${filters.join('.')}`) ? 'block' : 'none');
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>IMSLP</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a href="pages/subscription.php">Subscription</a>
    <a href="pages/login.php">Login</a>
    <a href="pages/about.php">About</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name" />
  <div id="filters">
    <div id="myBtnContainer">
      <p>Period</p>
      <button data-filter="Barok" class="btn">Barok</button>
      <button data-filter="Classic" class="btn">Classic</button>
      <button data-filter="Renaissance" class="btn">Renaissance</button>
      <button data-filter="Romantic" class="btn">Romantic</button>
    </div>
    <div id="myBtnContainer">
      <p>Composer</p>
      <button data-filter="DiLasso" class="btn">De Lassus</button>
      <button data-filter="Bach" class="btn">Bach</button>
      <button data-filter="Vivaldi" class="btn">Vivaldi</button>
      <button data-filter="Schubert" class="btn">Schubert</button>
      <button data-filter="Tchaikovsky" class="btn">Tchaikovsky</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="myUL">
    <div class="filterDiv Renaissance DiLasso">Lagrime de San Pietro</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Renaissance">Sweelinck</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Classic">Haydn</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Romantic">Wagner</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Classic">Mozart</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Barok Bach">Bach</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Classic">Beethoven</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Barok">Händel</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Barok Vivaldi">Vivaldi</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Renaissance">Obrecht</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Romantic Schubert">Schubert</div>
    <div class="filterDiv Romantic Tchaikovsky">Tchaikovsky</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! This helped me a lot. And it's clear that this way works way better than the way I did it before.